# How can I change the termination condition within a useEffect setInterval?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setinterval

A state (managed by a Zustand store) `isHighlighted` can be active for any amount of time.

When it's active, an element isHighlighted with an infinite pulsing animation.

Critically, this animation must last for a whole number of `animationPeriod_seconds` time - it should not stop mid-way through an animation.

Below is my attempt to achieve that, although there is a 'bug' in which after 1.5seconds, the animation loop starts again, then terminates after 0.5s. This is because at the end of the first interval, `sustainAnimation` is set to false, and the animation is restarted after the `if (!sustainAnimation)` condition.

Realistically, I only want the interval to terminate when `isHighlighted` is false, however if I put an `if` in to check for this, it will never run. This is because isHighlighted becomes effectively constant within the `useEffect`....

How can I achieve what I'm looking for? Do I need some useRef external to this which is checked in the interval?

```
  //isHighlights set to 'true' for 1.5s, then set to 'false'
  const animationPeriod_seconds = 1
  const [sustainAnimation, setSustainAnimation] = useState(false);
  const isHighlighted = useEditorStore((state) =>
    state.highlightedSocketKeys.has(socketKey)
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isHighlighted) {
      if (!sustainAnimation) {
        setSustainAnimation(true);
      }
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        //Would like to put a if(isHighlighted) here but it doesn't work because isHighlighted will always be 'true' here
        clearInterval(interval);
        setSustainAnimation(false);
      }, animationPeriod_seconds * 1000);
    }
  }, [isHighlighted, sustainAnimation]);

 // Later on, the animation is shown if (isHighlight || sustainAnimation)
```

Comment: It's probably quite tricky to get right. I would try to first solve how to add and remove an animation in a way that lets the animation finish in a sandbox without react. My thought goes into a direction where the `animation-iteration-count: var(--animate)` is controlled via a custom css property and I would switch the prop value via code from `infinite` to `1`

Comment: @Martin that's a great suggestion, I will give it a try.

Comment: Keeping track of the current interval ID and the duration of animation, and update them whenever `isHighlighted` changes. This what you want?